# Ping a NAS BOX before Rsync. If turned on then start Rsync if not then WOL and then ping before Rsync start - Linux

Tags: share, ping, rsync, mount

Please help.
I have been trying to run a script wherein first i need to check whether the NAS box is up by PING and if yes then mount the NAS and start rsync. BUt if the NAS is powered off, send a WOL packet and then (sleep 6m as i know that the NAS box takes 5 mins. before fully powered on and available on Network)PING again to make sure the NAS is up and then Mount the NAS and start Rsync.

### Below is the script i am using

```
 #!/bin/bash
VAR=`ping -s 1 -c 2 desknas > /dev/null; echo $?`

if [ $VAR -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "NAS BOX is up - Mounting NAS Share"
mount /mnt/NAS | echo "NAS Mounted Successfully"
fi

if [ $VAR -gt 0 ]; then
wakeonlan 00:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx | echo "NAS not turned on. WOL sent to NAS"
fi

sleep 6m
if [ $VAR -eq 0 ]; then
echo "NAS is UP - Mounting NAS Share"
mount /mnt/NAS | echo "NAS Mounted Successfully"
fi
```

---

The script works upto the point of waking up the NAS and then waits for 6mins and then exits without mounting the NAS share.

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong?? Why is it not going onto mounting the share??

Please HELP.

Regards,
Farooq Ahmed

Comment: What's the `|` operator? Since mount returns 0 on success, shouldn't you use `&&` ?

Comment: I have used | just to display the command that is running.Like for example wakeonlan command shows on the screen "NAS not turned on. WOL sent to NAS" while it sending the magic packets.

Comment: Hi Aif, Can you please rewrite the script and send it please??

Comment: just try to replace `|` with `&&`.

Comment: For all (|) of them ???

Comment: Tried it but it doesn't work. It goes through the part of wakeonlan and the waits for 6 mins and then just exits out.

Comment: Please help.... This is the output "Sending magic packet to 255.255.255.255:9 with 00:1f:c6:8d:a6:c5
NAS not turned on. WOL sent to NAS
"

Comment: It dosn't try to PING and the mount the share "if [ $VAR -eq 0 ]; then
echo "NAS is UP - Mounting NAS Share"
mount /mnt/NAS | echo "NAS Mounted Successfully"
fi" This is the bit i think it doesn't check. Please help

Comment: Quick help is required please.......

Answer (score 0):

After you wake up the NAS, before checking for the ping result, you should ping the machine again... Isn't it?

Happy New Year!

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR=`ping -s 1 -c 2 desknas > /dev/null; echo $?`
if [ $VAR -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "NAS BOX is up - Mounting NAS Share"
    mount /mnt/NAS && echo "NAS Mounted Successfully"
fi
if [ $VAR -gt 0 ]; then
    wakeonlan 00:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx && echo "NAS not turned on. WOL sent to NAS"
fi
sleep 6m
VAR=`ping -s 1 -c 2 desknas > /dev/null; echo $?`
if [ $VAR -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "NAS is UP - Mounting NAS Share"
    mount /mnt/NAS && echo "NAS Mounted Successfully"
fi
```

Comment: The machine which you are asking about is the NAS Box. I need to check that the NAS box is up before starting the rSync. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the task where I need to first check whether the NAS box is up by PING and if yes then mount the NAS and start rsync (i used dd command in the end). But if the NAS is powered off, send a WOL packet and then (sleep 6m as i know that the NAS box takes 5 mins. before fully powered on and available on Network)PING again to make sure the NAS is up and then Mount the NAS and start the backup process.

## Below is the code

```
#!/bin/bash

#####################VARIABLES DEFINED##########################

TIMESTAMP=`date +%d%m%y%s
LOGFILE=/root/logs/$TIMESTAMP/Rsync_Backup_`date +%d%m%y%s`.log
VAR=`ping -s 1 -c 2 desknas > /dev/null; echo $?
PING=`ping -s 1 -c 4 desknas > /dev/null; echo $?

################################################################

mkdir /root/logs/$TIMESTAMP
if [ $VAR -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "NAS BOX is up"
  if df | grep -q '/mnt/NAS$'
  then
    echo "Found mount point, running task"
    echo "Backup starts for the RasPi" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "=================================" >> $LOGFILE
    pv -tpreb /dev/mmcblk0 | dd of=/mnt/NAS/Admin01/RasPi_dd_image/RasPi_dd_image_`date +%d%m%y%s`.img bs=4M 2>> $LOGFILE
    echo "=================================" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "Backup Completed Successfully" >> $LOGFILE
    umount /mnt/NAS | echo "NAS UNMOUNTED" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "-----------------------------------------" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "Rsync Completed Successfully at $(date)" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "SSHing into NAS to perform Shutdown" >> $LOGFILE
    sshpass -p 'password' ssh desknas 'shutdown -p now' >> $LOGFILE
    sleep 5
    mail -a "From: RASeServer <example@email.com>" -s "RasPi Backup(dd) Status" user@gmail.com < $LOGFILE
  else
    echo "NAS not mounted - Mounting NAS Share" >> $LOGFILE
    mount /mnt/NAS | echo "NAS Mounted Successfully" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "Backup starts for the RasPi" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "=================================" >> $LOGFILE
    pv -tpreb /dev/mmcblk0 | dd of=/mnt/NAS/Admin01/RasPi_dd_image/RasPi_dd_image_`date +%d%m%y%s`.img bs=4M 2>> $LOGFILE
    echo "=================================" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "Backup Completed Successfully" >> $LOGFILE
    umount /mnt/NAS | echo "NAS UNMOUNTED" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "-----------------------------------------" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "Rsync Completed Successfully at $(date)" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "SSHing into NAS to perform Shutdown" >> $LOGFILE
    sshpass -p 'password' ssh desknas 'shutdown -p now' >> $LOGFILE
    sleep 5
    mail -a "From: RASeServer <example@email.com>" -s "RasPi Backup(dd) Status" user@gmail.com < $LOGFILE
  fi
fi
if [ $VAR -gt 0 ];then
  echo "Rsync Process starts at $(date)" >> $LOGFILE
  echo "-----------------------------------------" >> $LOGFILE
  wakeonlan 00:00:00:00:00:00 | echo "NAS not turned on. WOL sent to NAS" >> $LOGFILE
  sleep 6m | echo "Waiting 6 Minutes" >> $LOGFILE
  if [ $PING -eq 0 ];then
    echo "NAS is UP - Mounting NAS Share" >> $LOGFILE
    mount /mnt/NAS | echo "NAS Mounted Successfully" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "Backup starts for the RasPi" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "=================================" >> $LOGFILE
    pv -tpreb /dev/mmcblk0 | dd of=/mnt/NAS/Admin01/RasPi_dd_image/RasPi_dd_image_`date +%d%m%y%s`.img bs=4M 2>> $LOGFILE
    echo "=================================" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "Backup Completed Successfully" >> $LOGFILE
    umount /mnt/NAS | echo "NAS UNMOUNTED" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "-----------------------------------------" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "Rsync Completed Successfully at $(date)" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "SSHing into NAS to perform Shutdown" >> $LOGFILE
    sshpass -p 'password' ssh desknas 'shutdown -p now' >> $LOGFILE
    sleep 5
    mail -a "From: RASeServer <example@email.com>" -s "RasPi Backup(dd) Status" user@gmail.com < $LOGFILE
  else
    echo "NAS can't be turned on - Please Check Network Connections" |  mail -a "From: RASeServer <example@email.com>" -s "RasPi Backup(dd) Failed on $(date)" user@gmail.com
  fi
fi
```

Regards,
Farooq Ahmed

@Johannsa
@Aif